# A TPM error (7) occured attempting to read a pcr value

Tags: initramfs, tpm

I can't boot my PC! Every time I try to boot it I receive an error message. I know there's lots of posts for this but I tried them all and none worked. Here's a picture, too.

[image: screenshot of boot failure due to /dev/sda1 filesystem inconsistency and an initramfs BusyBox prompt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /` or `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdXX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX` # replacing XX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP. Your first fix gave the error message
`fsck: error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.etx2 for dev/sda1` but `sda1` is the right partition according to `gparted`. I can't get past the point where it says `(initframfs)` with a blinking cursor. I'm just trying to install Ubuntu 16.04...now I've lost my Windows10 boot. Dead laptop apart from booting from a live USB.
I'll try your second fix.

Comment: On my laptop, your second fix gave me the following output:

`fsck from util-linux 2.27.1`

`e2fsck 1.42.13 (17 May 2015)`

`/dev/sda1: clean, 190684/7168000 files, 1541056/28668160 blocks`

when running `fsck` from terminal after booting to the live USB. What does this mean?

Comment: @Jim421616 assuming that sda1 is the correct Ubuntu partition, fsck isn't finding any problem. Please start a new question with as many details as you can provide.

Comment: I've asked the question <a href = https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062721/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value-after-trying-to-install> here</a>.