# A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value after trying to install 16.04

Tags: 16.04, initramfs, tpm

I'm trying to revive an ageing laptop by installing Ubuntu 16.04 (I want to upgrade it to 18.04 eventually) over Windows 10. I made a live USB using `unetbootin` and a 16.04 distro from the Ubuntu website. I can boot from the USB to 'Try Ubuntu before installing', and it works fine. So I rebooted and chose to install fully. It seems to have installed fine, connecting to wifi, and loading files, right up to asking me to "restart the computer in order to use the new installation". When it reboots (after selecting HDD as boot drive), I get

```
A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
```

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925475/a-tpm-error-7-occured-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value) which contains two possible fixes. Upon trying the first fix, I got  the error message:

```
fsck: error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.etx2 for dev/sda1
```

but sda1 is the right partition according to gparted. I can't get past the point where it says (initframfs) with a blinking cursor.

Trying the second fix (booting from USB, using `gparted` and the running `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`) gave me the following output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17 May 2015)
/dev/sda1: clean, 190684/7168000 files, 1541056/28668160 blocks
```

which means that `fsck` isn't finding any problem.

If I enable TPM from the BIOS, I get to the GRUB menu. Selecting Ubuntu, it boots (after 30 seconds or so) to a screen that says:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=5e554f23-260a-4835-8b29-78e215786e09 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of builtin commands

(initramfs) #cursor#
```

And [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851975/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value) doesn't solve my problem, because I only have one SSD (I think), and I can't boot to a command prompt anyway.

So now I have a dead laptop apart from booting from a live USB.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you disable TPM in the BIOS, does it boot up properly?

Comment: No; when I wrote the question, TPM was disabled. I enabled it in the BIOS, and then wrote `If I enable TPM from the BIOS, it boots straight to a screen...`

Comment: You lost me a little bit... with TPM disabled, does the computer boot up properly... in both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Summary and clarification: with TPM disabled, I get `A TPM error (7) occurred...` and with it enabled, I get the GRUB menu; selecting Ubuntu, I get `Gave up waiting for a root device. ALERT! UUID=blah blah blah does not exist. Dropping to a shell!' 
and then the 
'BusyBox v1.22.1...` message

Comment: I just added some more detail to the second error message.

Comment: It seems the UUID of `/dev/sda1` has changed since you installed Ubuntu, possibly due to the switch from no TPM to TPM. You could recover the system from the busybox prompt (you need to get the correct UUID, taken from `blkid` into `grub.cfg`), but since it's a fresh install, it's probably easier to just reinstall (and not toggle the TPM inbetween installation and first boot).

Comment: I’ve lost count of the number of times I’ve reinstalled it! Always the same problem, whether or not I’ve changed the TPM setting.

Comment: At the initramfs prompt, type **blkid** or maybe **sudo blkid** and check the UUID's found. If it doesn't like those commands at the initramfs prompt, type **exit** and retry one of the blkid commands. Identify the UUID for the boot device (it may be different than the UUID identified in your error message), then boot to the GRUB menu, hit "e" to edit the boot script, and change the UUID to the one blkid shows, then hit ctrl-x or F10 to continue the boot with the new edits.

Comment: Typing `blkid` at the `initramfs` prompt had no effect other than to perform a newline and give me the same prompt. Typing `sudo blkid` returned `/bin/sh: sudo: not found`. Just about ready to give up on Ubuntu permanently.

Comment: Typing `help` at the prompt gives me the following list of possible commands: `. : [ alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export false getopts hash help history let local printf pwd read readonly return set shift test times trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait [ [[ acpid ash awk basename blockdev cat chmod chroot chvt clear cmp cp cut deallocvt devmem df dnsdomainname du dumkmap echo egrep env expr false fbset fdflush fgrep find fstrim grep gunzip gzip hostname hwclock ifconfig ip kill ln loadfont loafkmap ls lzop mkdir mkfifo mknod mkswap mktemp modinfo more`...

Comment: ...`mount mv openvt pidof printf ps pwd realink reset rm rmdir sed seq setkeycodes sh sleep sort stat static-sh stty switch_root sync tail tee test touch tr true tty umount uname uniq unzlop wc wget which yes zcat`. I know what only a handful of those mean.

Comment: I've asked another question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063038/ubuntu-18-04-live-usb-not-loading-mismatched-uuids with some screenshots of the GRUB menu and UUIDs.